# C++: Get value of variable after performing divide and assignment operator:

Tags: c++

I am trying to get a value of a variable "pesoil" before its converted to to mm month^-1

```
pesoil = beta * rnsoil + CPAIR * RHOAIR * exp_h * vpdo / r_as;
pesoil /= (beta + PSY * exp_h * (1.0 + r_ss / r_as))); // W m^-2
pesoil *= (etimes * ndays[dm]) / LAMBDA;                          // convert to mm month^-1
```

can I do it like this? or will this mess up value stored in "pesoil"

```
  epotential_W = (pesoil /= (beta + PSY * exp_h * (1.0 + r_ss / r_as))); // W m^-2
```

Comment: Try it and tell us?

Comment: You can do `epotential_W = pesoil;` before doing the conversion to *"mm month^-1"* as well

Comment: Writing it like that is allowed, but I still wouldn't do it because it makes the code harder to read.

Comment: IMHO, you don't gain any benefits by placing the entire expression on one line.  If you use some `const` temporary variables for each term, you can use a debugger and verify that each term is calculating correctly.